# Парсинг Json c помощью jackson.core

Tags: android, json, парсер

Использую jackson.core.JsonParser..
Почему то не могу получить поле image..

Есть предположение что из-за того что там не string а массив байтов.. Но как достать массив?

response json: 
[{"Text":null,"Image":[29,127,90],"Sound":null,"LastIndex":1,"DateTime":"10/14/2015 1:52:21 PM"}]

```
        JsonFactory jsonfactory = new JsonFactory();
        File source = new File(filename);
        JsonParser parser = jsonfactory.createJsonParser(source);
        int ID=0;


        while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
            String token = parser.getCurrentName();
            if ("Image".equals(token)) {
                parser.nextToken();
                _image = parser.getText(); // выводит только [ в место [29,127,90] 
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что нельзя прочесть массив как одно значение.
Нужно открыть новый цикл `while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {...}` и получить элемент за элементом. Как то так

```
while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
        String token = parser.getCurrentName();
        if ("Image".equals(token)) {
            parser.nextToken();
            while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
                // считать один за одним элементы массива
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Да, вы правы! Спасибо!
Вот так получаю я

if ("Image".equals(token)) {
                    parser.nextToken();
                    String key ="";
                    while (!key.equalsIgnoreCase("]")){
                        _image = _image + "," +parser.getText();
                        key = parser.getText();
                        parser.nextValue();
                    }


                    Log.i("MyLogIlnar", "Image : " + _image);
                    parser.nextToken();
                    token = parser.getCurrentName();
                }